# Is it true that any non-empty set can be indexed by some index set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

<strike>Motivation: If the definition of Cartesian product of more than one set relies on the concept of indexed family of sets, then the Cartesian product of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, say, who have not yet constituted an indexed family, need to be indexed first. In general, let $\mathcal{C}$ be a set of sets, then the Cartesian product of all the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ requires $\mathcal{C}$ to be indexed first. But can we?</strike>

From a given non-empty set $\mathcal{C}$ (non-empty because I am afraid of the case when $\mathcal{C}=\emptyset$), how can we construct from axioms of set theory 1) a set $I$, and 2) a relation $\sim\subset I\times\mathcal{C}$, so that $\sim$ is a map? Do we need the additional condition that $\mathcal{C}$ is a set of sets, considering the axiom of union would be of any help?

My idea is a set can always be indexed by itself. Since $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{C}$ is always ture. By the axiom of extension that means for each element of the lhs one can find one of the rhs so that they equals, therefore there always exists an identity map $\mathrm{id}_\mathcal{C}$ for any given set $\mathcal{C}$ that of course is bijective. That is, given a set $\mathcal{C}$ and using the naturally exists identity map $\mathrm{id}_\mathcal{C}$ there exist a family $\left\langle A_i\right\rangle_{i\in\mathcal{C}}$ with $A_i=i,\forall i\in\mathcal{C}$. If anywhere the axiom of choice is need then use it.

For example, considering the definition of Catesian product of an $I$-indexed family of set $\left\langle X_i\right\rangle_{i\in I}$, $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, to be the sets of all families $\left\langle x_i\right\rangle_{i\in I}$ with $x_i\in X_i,\forall i\in I$, we can denote the Cartesian product of a non-empty set of sets $\mathcal{C}$ by $\prod_{X\in\mathcal{C}}X\equiv\prod_{i\in\mathcal{C}}A_i$, where $A_i=i,\forall i\in\mathcal{C}$. May it serve as a definition of Catesian product of many pair-wise distinct sets?

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. The definition of cartesian product does not require any notion of indexing.

Comment: (It might help to include the definition you're working with.)

Comment: You're right that if the factors in the desired product are all distinct, then the set of factors can serve as the index set for the product. The point of having a separate index set is to allow us to describe products with repeated factors.

Comment: @ZhenLin I have deleted the first paragraph. Now the inquiry is put in a different way.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for the suggestion. The definition is added, and per the comment of others, I revised the question into the last sentence. If C is a non-empty set then its elements should be distinct. So, the question is indeed about Cartesian product of distinct factors.

Comment: Your idea makes sense and can serve as a definition in that case. The index set style might still be preferable since it prevents the product from "accidentally" collapsing multiple elements of $\mathcal C$ into one factor if they happen to be equal. The index set determines the "shape" of the product.

Comment: @Karl What has been bothering me is indeed the issue about the Cartesian product like A x B x B. However, whenever anyone wants to make a Cartesian product from more than two sets sporadically, they need to know about natural number. A person who don't know how to count to n cannot cultivate the idea that he want to calculate a Cartesian product n times. On the other hand, one can never specify, if he what to calculate a Cartesian product uncountably many times out of finite number of sets, the order of the product, so this question never exists...

Comment: @Karl ... Then it makes sense to say that the "rest situations" besides what I have written in the question always come with a family indexed by natural number; I don't need to worry about finding a indexing mapping for them anyway.

Comment: What about infinite products like $X^\Bbb R$? We don't need to order the factors for a product to make sense, we just need to index them.

Comment: @Karl Thank you for your comment! Now I understand my motivation is not well-defined.  The real motivation is to ask whether for *any* case there is always a way to do the thing I want, whereas for each case I may want to do an uncountable number of things. This question has no answer of course. I should have asked whether there is a case where the Cartesian product I want to do happens to be impossible based on the axioms since the existence of the index mapping is not supported by axioms. But even this question is rude to ask.

Comment: @Karl I am doing the exercise of $X^\mathbb{R}$, and I feel that I can write down the indexing mapping. The inspiration you gave me is that one should only do the exercises but not asking rude questions.

Comment: Your question is reasonable! The point is that the index set definition formalizes what it means to properly *describe* a Cartesian product. The only product-like things I can think of that don't admit such a description are too large to be sets because the index set and/or factors are proper classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142156/discussion-between-andrew-sun-and-karl).